# Sentry - scrubbing local variables sensitive data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sentry

I would like to scrub sensitive data from Python before I send it to Sentry

However, in method `before_send` and `truncate_breadcrumb_message` I am not sure where I can get the list of local variables and scrub them.

```
sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn=settings.get('SENTRY_DSN', ""),
    before_breadcrumb=truncate_breadcrumb_message,
    integrations=[FlaskIntegration()],
    before_send=sanitize_sentry_event,
)

def sanitize_sentry_event(event, hint):
    pass

def truncate_breadcrumb_message(crumb, hint):
    pass

def raise_execption(password):
    auth = 5
    raise Exception()
```

In the above method, I wouldn't want password and auth to be send to Sentry at all.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you looked at `locals()` and `globals()`? You can operate on them like dictionaries.

Comment: in before_send method?

Comment: If you call `del password` and `del auth` before `raise`, do you still see them in Sentry?

Comment: I am looking for a global place to do it for all method for variable password / auth etc

Comment: You might want to look into https://github.com/untitaker/python-sensitive-variables for selective cleanup of local variables. Disclaimer: I am the author, and the project is not affiliated with Sentry. The answer I posted is the Sentry-official approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event` is a JSON payload that contains the same exact JSON you see in the "JSON" download in Sentry's UI. So you have a event like this:

```
{
  "exception": {
    "values": [
      {
        "stacktrace": {
          "frames": [
            {"vars": ...}
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And you want to remove `vars`, you need to do this:

```
def sanitize_sentry_event(event, hint):
    for exception in event.get("exception", {}).get("values", []):
        for frame in exception.get("stacktrace", {}).get("frames", []):
            frame.pop("vars", None)

    for exception in event.get("threads", {}).get("values", []):
        for frame in exception.get("stacktrace", {}).get("frames", []):
            frame.pop("vars", None)


    return event
```

You probably want to wrap the entire function body with a try-except. If the function raises an exception the event is dropped. Make sure to test this using `init(debug=True)` to see all exceptions your `before_send` hook might throw

Answer (score 1):

found it [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/211)

**Code for anyone** who migrated from [raven](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/master/raven/processors.py) and wants to use **raven processors** / **sanitize_keys**

```
from raven.processors import SanitizeKeysProcessor, SanitizePasswordsProcessor

class FakeRavenClient:
    sanitize_keys = [
        'card_number',
        'card_cvv',
        'card_expiration_date',
    ]

processors = [
    SanitizePasswordsProcessor(FakeRavenClient),
    SanitizeKeysProcessor(FakeRavenClient),
]

def before_send(event, hint):
    for processor in processors:
        event = processor.process(event)
    return event

sentry_sdk.init(
    before_send=before_send,
)
```

Comment: FYI: contexts are not sanitized